# Draw box around plot or fill plot area in tikz/pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to create a plot in `tikz`/`pgfplots` with a number of `\addplot table` commands. Each of the tables is the result of a simulation. I need to add a box around each simulation's result or fill the area covered by the plot. How can I do that?

I can not use the start and end coordinates of the plot (for fitting a node around them) because the start and end points can be anywhere within the area covered by the result.

Here is an mwe that illustrates the kind of plot I have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates{
                (0,0)
                (2,1)
                (1,1)
                (2,2)
                (0,2)
            };
            \addplot coordinates{
                (3,3)
                (5,4)
                (4,4)
                (5,5)
                (3,5)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I need a box around each of the plots (or a filled background). Again, using a node to fit start and end of the plots won't work because start and end don't define a rectangle that encloses the plot. The plots won't be so similar to each other with real world data.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a minimal example document with some dummy data that demonstrates the kind of situation you're thinking of?

Comment: @Jake: I'll add an example

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `\pgf@pathminx` and `\pgf@pathmaxy` commands, which hold the current path's minimum and maximum x and y coordinates, to draw a rectangle around the plot. Here's a macro `\drawplotbox` that can be called at the end of the `\addplot` command. The style of the box is controlled by a key called `plot box`, the padding of the box can be set using `plot box padding`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\drawplotbox}{
(\pgf@pathminx,\pgf@pathminy) coordinate (current plot south west)
            (\pgf@pathmaxx,\pgf@pathmaxy) coordinate (current plot north east);
            \draw [plot box] ([shift={(-135:1.41*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/plot box padding})}]current plot south west) rectangle ([shift={(45:1.41*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/plot box padding})}]current plot north east);
}

\tikzset{
    plot box/.style={
        thick, rounded corners, orange
    },
    plot box padding/.initial=5pt
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates{
                (0,0)
                (2,1)
                (1,1)
                (2,2)
                (0,2)
            } \drawplotbox;
            \addplot +[plot box/.append style=black, plot box padding=10pt] coordinates{
                (3,3)
                (5,4)
                (4,4)
                (5,5)
                (3,5)
            } \drawplotbox;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! I was thinking of `current path bounding box` node for this.